# How to run command module avail using subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to call module avail and module laod during my python code using subprocess.call which is something like this.

```
    subprocess.call(['module avail calibre','&','module load calibre'])
```

But when I run this code it returns:

OSERROR
(2, 'No such file or directory')

Any help regarding subprocess??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to run this shell command:

```
$ module avail calibre & module load calibre
```

with subprocess try:

```
subprocess.call(['module','avail','calibre','&','module','load','calibre'])
```

or:

```
subprocess.call('module avail calibre & module load calibre',shell=True)
```

Comment: Got this reult running the second one and first one still gives same OSERROR                                                        /bin/sh: module: command not found
/bin/sh: calibredrv: command not found
/bin/sh: module: command not found

Comment: This means that your python interpreter can't find the `module` executable. You can try to use absolute paths, like this: `subprocess.call(['/abs/path/to/module','avail','calibre','&','/abs/path/to/module','load','calibre'])`

Comment: @Enrico That command line is expected to be interpreted by a shell. It wont work as expected when run without a shell. The `&` and what follows will just be passed as parameters to "module" command in the first case.

Comment: can it be done in a way that i write a bunch of commands in a scrpit and then pass that script using subprocess....if yes Could you help in giving syntax for that